# Magento Wordpress installation Fishpig auto login not working

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, fishpig

Since my magento store is upgraded to 1.9.1.0 I have problems with the Fishpig plugin for Wordpress. I tried to upgrade this to version 3 but then my complete website gives a white page, so I have now installed 2.2.0 for Fishpig.

My blog is shown now on the frontend but the Backend doesn't work anymore. When I go to wordpress in the menu and click on WP Admin I got an error page:

There has been an error processing your request.
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db044833_prd.wordpress_autologin' doesn't exist,query was: SELECT `e`.* FROM `wordpress_autologin` AS `e` WHERE (e.store_id=0) AND (user_id='4') LIMIT 1

If I try to login by www.pixie.nl/wp/wp-admin I get this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_is_mobile() in /home/users/pixieftp/pixie.nl/wp/wp-login.php on line 39

My webbuilder who did the upgrade doesn't know how to solve this so I contacted Ben from Fishpig, he  advised to purchase the Installation Service, which I did, but I didn't hear anything from him. I mailed several times but no answer and still no working backend.

How could I solve this?

Miranda

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the [Magento WordPress Integration](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/) to the latest version as this uses a much improved auto-login system. If after doing this you have a blank white page, this means that you have a fatal PHP error that is hidden because of your settings. To reveal the error, open your index.php file and uncomment the following line:

```
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

After doing this, the blank white page will reveal a PHP error that you should aim to fix (feel free to post it here in a new question and I can help).